# Installing nvidia drivers on server 2012

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2012-r2, nvidia-graphics-card

I was trying to install the nvidia drivers for my server running windows server 2012 R2.

I am not sure that I was sucsessful, in that I was able to use pnputil to load the inf file (as per [this](http://blog.ittoby.com/2013/02/installing-nvidia-consumer-drivers-on.html) article) but I am not sure if it worked properly (the program said it was sucsessful, but it also shows that there is a 3D controller that does not have a driver in device manager)

How can I properly install this driver, or see if it is already installed?

I am not looking for what is necessarily the most recent driver, but any driver would be better than what I have.

While I happen to have a GTX 765, this should be a relatively general question that applies to many video drivers.

**Edit:** The drivers were not installed (in the sense that performance was unchanged at all when attempting to play anything, and it still does not show up in device manager)

Comment: What version of the driver where you attempting to install, Windows 8 64 bit, or something else?

Comment: Did you enable the Desktop Experience feature found under User interface and infrastructure?

Comment: @harrymc yes, it is installed

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes, but apparently its the same for than and 7 and vista (file name is: 320.49-desktop-win8-win7-winvista-64bit-english-whql)

Comment: Is the same driver suggested by [Automatically find drivers for my NVIDIA products](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) ? Do you have any messages in Event Viewer ? And what is your computer model ?

Comment: @harrymc I get this message: The NVIDIA Smart Scan was unable to evaluate your system hardware. Please use Option 1 to manually find drivers for your NVIDIA products.

Comment: Please answer my other questions, since it seems to me that you are trying to install Server 2012 on a laptop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10074/discussion-between-soandos-and-harrymc)

Comment: You could also try the [Nvidia beta drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us) for Windows 8.

Comment: @harrymc no change.

Comment: Do you have any messages in Event Viewer ? What is your computer model ? Do you have GTX 765m (765 may not exist) ?

Comment: @harrymc nothing related, http://pastebin.com/RuEm2Wxa, yes

Comment: have you tried to expand the EXE and install it with DeviceManager?

Comment: I've attempted to install graphic drivers manually with Device Manager, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

I have a Nvidia Geforce GTX 660 Ti and i am writing this from a Windows Server 2012 R2, and 2 Displays ("Surroundview") , one with 4K UHD solution, one with full hd.

The INSTALLER from Nvidia is not working.

Follow this instruction

1. Download the Win 8.1. Driver for your Video Card, but not the last one,
   but the "GeForce-Game-ready-Treiber, WHQL-Version"
   This Driver ist a "MS Signed" Driver.

My Version is 355.82, Windows 7 64-bit, Windows 8.1 64-bit, Windows 8 64-bit, Windows Vista 64-bit

1. Lern mal mehr english
   (http://www.nvidia.de/download/driverResults.aspx/90633/de)
2. Unzip the driver.
3. Go to Device Manager, 
   (Right Mouse click  on windows Start botton)
4. Video Card 
   6  Rightclick, new driver, and search the Directory where you unzipped the downloaded driver
5. Let search it automatically.
6. Displays getting dark
7. Scream for fun, you have 2 Displays working now with Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter, running on hardware, video card is Palit GTX 660 Ti, Display 1 is connected to display port and its running DAMN 4K / UHD solution. Display 2 is running full HD and is connected to the DVI-D.

Comment: Please write in English, that is the language of this forum.

Comment: Worked beautifully on Windows Server 2012 R2. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Your laptop is an impressively well-muscled gaming computer, but it is still a laptop.

A laptop is always a risky platform for running a server version of Windows,
which goes double for R2 which is just a preview and not even the final version.
Microsoft does not support laptop-specific hardware on its server platforms,
and neither does Nvidia.

As another consideration, it is not advisable to have a patched operating system
as you are trying to do. You take the risk of a future Windows Update
rendering your computer unusable.

And on the other hand, Windows Server 2012 is not a perfect desktop platform.
Also, many products which are free on the client versions of Windows will
refuse to install on a server version without a paid license.

Although this does not answer your question, in view of all the above points
my advice is to return your laptop to Windows 8.
As you do not have a touch-screen, I would even advice downgrading to Windows 7 (if possible).

Comment: Why go down to 7? (I have been using 8 since before it came out)

Comment: For stability - I have answered quite a few posts for Win8. But if Win8 suits you fine, then go ahead. I personally don't see Metro as suitable for power-users, but certainly the underlying OS in Win8 is more advanced than 7 (and Start button replacements do exist). You can still use Server 2012 in a VM.

Comment: I disagree with this answer.  I exclusively run server OS's at work to do my job.  I am still on Windows 2008R2 datacenter, running like a Windows 7 desktop, with the added benefit of being able to install just about anything including clustering, hyper-v, and full versions of SQL.  I can't switch to 2012R2 until I figure out the glitches, such as why won't a graphic driver install?

Comment: To the downvoter: This is an old answer from 2013, probably outdated by now. So no point in downvoting it on 2015.

Answer (score -2):

Just in case someone else comes to look for this. I installed the following drivers for my Geforce GTX 550TI: 388.13-desktop-win8-win7-64bit-international-whql.exe 
And ran it normal and it installed fine on my Windows server 2012 r2 system.

I searched for windows 8.1 drivers under geforce 500 series.